# WCF exceptions being ignored in WPF client

Tags: .net, wpf, wcf, exception, faultexception

I have a WCF service library hosted in a Windows Service. I have spent all day testing numerous scenarios with much success. However, as the application is now, I have a problem with uncaught exceptions, my `FaultException<ExceptionFault>`, simply being logged by the WCF service, and then disappearing. `ExceptionFault` is a simple `DataContract` model that has only three string values with data describing an exception.

The WCF service uses a timer to call the following methods every 30 seconds:

```
public int Process(bool isForced)
{
    try
    {
        var count = ProcessListings();
        return count;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        _logger.ErrorWithCallStack("Error while processing listings. " + ex.GetType().Name + ": " + ex.Message, ex, ex.StackTrace);
        if (ex is SchedulerException)
        {
            throw new FaultException<ExceptionFault>(new ExceptionFault(ex), ex.Message);
        }
        throw;
    }
}

private static int ProcessListings()
{
    if (processCount % 3 == 0)
    {
        throw new SchedulerException("ProcessListings failed.");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The client is a viewmodel in a WPF app. It has a command to override the timer and force `Process` to execute, by calling the WCF proxy's `ProcessAsync` method. When I use this, the client catches the `FaultException<ExceptionFault>` and properly shows a dialogue. When the service itself executes the `Process` method, one the timer's `Elapsed` event, the same exception is thrown (every third time), but although this exception is not handled anywhere, the service simply ignores it and processes again the next time the timer fires.

I know exceptions in timer events are swallowed, but in this case I simply don't know what else to do. I am handling four cases of unhandled exception in the client, and if I move the timer into the windows service, and catch an unhandled exception there, where it occurs, how do I communicate it back to the WPF client?